# get absolute path in XML

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, xml

I am trying to add in my footer links, when a user is logged in, a link to the order history page.

This is what I added to my customer.xml file

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="sales">
    <label>My Orders</label>
    <url>sales/order/history/</url>
    <title>My Orders</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>2</position>
</action>
```

The link is added and displayed in the right way, but the href is not an absolute URL, it is relative and it does not bring to the right page. How can I obtain the absolute URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close.
The only thing you need to change is  `<prepare />` to `<prepare>true</prepare>`.